# C++ : int _b(di*3) convert to C

Tags: c++, c, int

A friend gave me some code in C++ to convert to C.  Can you help me understand what it does?

```
for (int _b(di*3), ddi = _b; ddi < _b+3; ++ddi)

 Specifically this bit : int _b(di*3) 

 // _b is not a function;
```

Comment: I think _b is a class and _b(di*3) is the CTOR of that class. Why don't you look up the symbol _b ?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a constructor call, i.e. a C++ way of saying:

```
int _b = di * 3;
```